# Customisation of Vim color scheme

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I love the colorscheme: vivid chalk in Vim; but the color of the code folding is somehow too distracting for me. Can anyone get me some pointers to change it?

[image: Blue fold]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:help` command will aid you much on your journeys in vim. For instance, `:help colorscheme`, `:help highlight`, or `:help syntax` will all guide you to vim's documentation file on syntax highlighting. Reading this document would be ideal, but that does require some time. So if you're looking for something in particular use the `/search<cr>` command in normal mode. For instance, I can type `:help colorscheme<Enter>/fold<Enter>` and the answer reveals itself.

As we can see, vim's colors for folds are set by the `Folded` highlight group. Change or comment out this line in your colorscheme to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, have been trying to modify this for a while in my colorscheme without much success:

`call s:hibg("Folded"    ,"#110077","DarkBlue",17)
call s:hifg("Folded"    ,"#aaddee","LightCyan",63)
`

Comment: Its did work, I had to modify some theme specific meta info to get it to work. Thanks for your time!